# print unique values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':['a','b','d','d'],'c':['v','v','g','w']})
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.unique().shape[0]))
```

above code will print count of unique values in each columns. I want to print count of unique values only for columns of 'object' type.

is there any way to filter only 'object' columns

Comment: you're going to want to check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `select_dtypes()` as [@JulianCienfuegos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42863601/5741205) has already said in conjunction with [nunique()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
In [9]: df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
Out[9]:
b    3
c    3
dtype: int64
```

As [@root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863523/print-unique-values-in-pandas-data-frame/42863618?noredirect=1#comment72833349_42863618) has added in the comment starting with Pandas 0.20.0 it should be possible to use `DataFrame.nunique()`:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).nunique()
```

Comment: As a note to future readers, `DataFrame.nunique` will be available in version 0.20.0, so `apply` will not be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Using `df.dtypes`

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].apply(pd.Series.nunique)

b    3
c    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

First select only the subset of the type you want.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html